# trying to implement breadth first search visualiser need help in animating the process

Tags: processing, p5.js

so i already have implemented the static version of the algorithm which draws out the path from starting node to ending node. What i need help is in how can i animate this process. Any help will be appreciated.
Here the link to the GitHub page of the project

visit: https://a8hay.github.io/path-finding-algo-simulations/

I already tried few things but nothing is working like i tried highlighting every neighboring cell that starting node visits each frame in draw loop but that is not working.?

Comment: it looks good to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty cool !

To visualise each step you would need to record it so you can visualise it afterwards.
(For example [here](https://github.com/a8hay/path-finding-algo-simulations/blob/master/bfs.js#L23) and [here](https://github.com/a8hay/path-finding-algo-simulations/blob/master/bfs.js#L35)

There are a few ways to do that.
For example:

1. you would record the a deep copy of the full grid data which you could later display/render and even debug/display additional visualisation data. [How to Deep Copy  Objects and Arrays in JavaScript](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-deep-copy-objects-and-arrays-in-javascript-7c911359b089) is a pretty good guide.
2. you could render a frame for each step and record it an list for layer visualisation playback

Currently you can't visualise the steps individually because of the blocking `while` loops which mess with rendering, but nothing is stopping you for explicitly calling `draw()` to render and [`get()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/get) to clone the frame for later:

```js
// XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX HUD VARIABLES XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
let startButton;
let resetButton;
let cellType;
let algoType;
// XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX HUD VARIABLES XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

// XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX SKETCH VARIABLES XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
let GRID = [];
let cellSize = 15;
let startX;
let startY;
let endX;
let endY;
// XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX SKETCH VARIABLES XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
// holds a grid per iteration step
let algoVisSteps = [];
// current iteration step counter
let algoVisStep = 0;
// display the visualisation or not
let displayAlgoViz = false;
// visualisation interval

function setup() {
  createCanvas(675, 315);
  initialiseGrid();
  createHud();
}

function draw() {
  background(100);
  
  if(displayAlgoViz){
    image(algoVisSteps[algoVisStep],0,0);
    // gotoNextFrame();
    algoVisStep = (algoVisStep + 1) % algoVisSteps.length;
  }else{
    // draw the grid
    for (let row = 0; row < GRID.length; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < GRID[0].length; col++) {
        GRID[row][col].show();
      }
    }
  
    placeMarkers();
  }
}

function placeMarkers() {
  let posx = floor(map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, GRID[0].length));
  let posy = floor(map(mouseY, 0, height, 0, GRID.length));
  let markerType = cellType.value();

  if (posx >= 0 && posy >= 0 && posx < GRID[0].length && posy < GRID.length) {
    if (mouseIsPressed && markerType == "START") {
      GRID[startX][startY].isStart = false;
      GRID[posy][posx].isStart = true;
      startX = posy;
      startY = posx;
    }
    if (mouseIsPressed && markerType == "END") {
      GRID[endX][endY].isEnd = false;
      GRID[posy][posx].isEnd = true;
      endX = posy;
      endY = posx;
    }
    if (mouseIsPressed && markerType == "WALLS") {
      GRID[posy][posx].isWall = true;
    }
  }
}

function createHud() {
  startButton = createButton("START");
  startButton.mousePressed(applyAlgo);
  resetButton = createButton("RESET");
  resetButton.mousePressed(initialiseGrid);

  cellType = createSelect();
  cellType.option("WALLS");
  cellType.option("START");
  cellType.option("END");

  algoType = createSelect();
  algoType.option("BREADTH FIRST SEARCH!");
  algoType.option("DEPTH FIRST SEARCH");
  algoType.option("DIJKASHTRA");
  algoType.option("A*");
}

function initialiseGrid() {
  resetVisualisation();
  GRID = create2dArray(floor(height / cellSize), floor(width / cellSize));

  for (let col = 0; col < GRID[0].length; col++) {
    for (let row = 0; row < GRID.length; row++) {
      let newCell = new Cell(col * cellSize, row * cellSize);
      GRID[row][col] = newCell;
    }
  }

  startX = 0;
  startY = 0;
  GRID[startX][startY].isStart = true;
  endX = GRID.length - 1;
  endY = GRID[0].length - 1;
  GRID[endX][endY].isEnd = true;

  addNeighbours();
}

// XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX HELPER FUNCTIONS XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
function create2dArray(m, n) {
  // array of m rows and n columns
  resultArray = [];
  for (let row = 0; row < m; row++) {
    let tempRow = [];
    for (let col = 0; col < n; col++) {
      tempRow.push(0);
    }
    resultArray.push(tempRow);
  }
  return resultArray;
}

function applyAlgo() {
  algo = algoType.value();
  if (algo === "BREADTH FIRST SEARCH!") {
    bfs();
    startAlgoVisualisation();
  }else{
    console.warn(algo,"not yet implemented");
  }
}

function addNeighbours() {
  // add only non diagonal elements
  // add neighbours of non boundary cells
  for (let row = 1; row < GRID.length - 1; row++) {
    for (let col = 1; col < GRID[0].length - 1; col++) {
      let current = GRID[row][col];
      current.neighbours = [
        GRID[row - 1][col],
        GRID[row][col - 1],
        GRID[row + 1][col],
        GRID[row][col + 1]
      ];
    }
  }
  // add neighbours of upper and lower boundary cells
  for (let col = 1; col < GRID[0].length - 1; col++) {
    let upper_boundary = GRID[0][col];
    upper_boundary.neighbours = [
      GRID[0][col - 1],
      GRID[0][col + 1],
      GRID[1][col]
    ];
    let lower_boundary = GRID[GRID.length - 1][col];
    lower_boundary.neighbours = [
      GRID[GRID.length - 1][col - 1],
      GRID[GRID.length - 1][col + 1],
      GRID[GRID.length - 1 - 1][col]
    ];
  }
  // add neighbours of left and right boundary cells
  for (let row = 1; row < GRID.length - 1; row++) {
    let left_boundary = GRID[row][0];
    left_boundary.neighbours = [
      GRID[row - 1][0],
      GRID[row + 1][0],
      GRID[row][1]
    ];
    let right_boundary = GRID[row][GRID[0].length - 1];
    right_boundary.neighbours = [
      GRID[row - 1][GRID[0].length - 1],
      GRID[row + 1][GRID[0].length - 1],
      GRID[row][GRID[0].length - 1 - 1]
    ];
  }
  // add neighbours of four corner cells
  let upper_left_corner = GRID[0][0];
  upper_left_corner.neighbours = [GRID[0 + 1][0], GRID[0][0 + 1]];

  let upper_right_corner = GRID[0][GRID[0].length - 1];
  upper_right_corner.neighbours = [
    GRID[0 + 1][GRID[0].length - 1],
    GRID[0][GRID[0].length - 1 - 1]
  ];

  let lower_right_corner = GRID[GRID.length - 1][GRID[0].length - 1];
  lower_right_corner.neighbours = [
    GRID[GRID.length - 1 - 1][GRID[0].length - 1],
    GRID[GRID.length - 1][GRID[0].length - 1 - 1]
  ];

  let lower_left_corner = GRID[GRID.length - 1][0];
  lower_left_corner.neighbours = [
    GRID[GRID.length - 1 - 1][0],
    GRID[GRID.length - 1][0 + 1]
  ];
}
// XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX HELPER FUNCTIONS XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
function addVisualisationStep(){
  draw();
  algoVisSteps.push(get());
  console.log("recorded",algoVisSteps.length,"frames");
}

function startAlgoVisualisation(){
  displayAlgoViz = true;
}

function stopAlgoVisualisation(){
  displayAlgoViz = false;
}

function resetVisualisation(){
  stopAlgoVisualisation();
  algoVisStep = 0;
  while(algoVisSteps.length > 0){
    delete algoVisSteps[0];
    algoVisSteps.shift();
  }
}

// BFS
function bfs() {
  console.log("applying BREADTH FIRST SEARCH");
  let startNode = GRID[startX][startY];
  let endNode = GRID[endX][endY];
  let Q = [];

  startNode.isDiscovered = true;
  Q.push(startNode);

  while (Q.length > 0) {
    let current = Q.shift();
    if (current == endNode) {
      console.log("found end node");
      break;
    } else {
      for (let nebr of current.neighbours) {
        if (nebr.isWall) {
          continue;
        }
        if (!nebr.isDiscovered) {
          nebr.isDiscovered = true;
          nebr.parent = current;
          Q.push(nebr);
          addVisualisationStep();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //   mark the cells which are in the path(that is solution path bw start and end)
  let end = endNode;
  while (end.parent != null) {
    if (!end.isStart) {
      end.isPath = true;
    }
    addVisualisationStep();
    end = end.parent;
  }
}

// Cell

class Cell {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.isStart = false;
    this.isEnd = false;
    this.isWall = false;
    this.isDiscovered = false;
    this.isPath = false;
    this.parent = null;
    this.neighbours = [];
    this.clr = [255, 255, 255, 255];
  }

  show() {
    if (this.isStart) {
      this.clr = [0, 255, 0, 255];
    } else {
      this.clr = [255, 255, 255, 255];
    }
    if (this.isEnd) {
      this.clr = [255, 0, 0, 255];
    }
    if (this.isWall) {
      this.clr = [51, 51, 51, 255];
    }
    if (this.isDiscovered && !this.isStart) {
      this.clr = [0, 255, 255, 180];
    }
    if (this.isPath) {
      this.clr = [255, 255, 0, 255];
    }
    stroke(115);
    fill(this.clr[0], this.clr[1], this.clr[2], this.clr[3]);
    rect(this.x, this.y, cellSize, cellSize);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

[image: breadth first path algorithm visualisation using coloured squares in a grid]

Notice I've reduced the size of the rendering to save on RAM.
For a simulation with a large number of frames that are high resolution it will get expensive.

This is where you would rationalise what is the smallest piece of information you could store per frame to redraw/visualise the algorithm

**Update**

Here's a version that does a shallow copy of grid, as in simply copies only the necessary data to render the grid (position, state), but discards search related data (e.g. `isParent`/`neighbours`/etc.):

```js
// XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX HUD VARIABLES XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
let startButton;
let resetButton;
let cellType;
let algoType;
// XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX HUD VARIABLES XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

// XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX SKETCH VARIABLES XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
let GRID = [];
let cellSize = 15;
let startX;
let startY;
let endX;
let endY;
// XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX SKETCH VARIABLES XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
// holds a grid per iteration step
let algoVisSteps = [];
// current iteration step counter
let algoVisStep = 0;
// display the visualisation or not
let displayAlgoViz = false;
// visualisation interval

function setup() {
  createCanvas(675, 315);
  initialiseGrid();
  createHud();
}

function draw() {
  background(100);
  
  if(displayAlgoViz){
    drawGrid(algoVisSteps[algoVisStep]);
    // gotoNextFrame();
    algoVisStep = (algoVisStep + 1) % algoVisSteps.length;
  }else{
    
    drawGrid(GRID);
    
    placeMarkers();
  }
}

function drawGrid(GRID){
  // draw the grid
  for (let row = 0; row < GRID.length; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < GRID[0].length; col++) {
      GRID[row][col].show();
    }
  }
}

function placeMarkers() {
  let posx = floor(map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, GRID[0].length));
  let posy = floor(map(mouseY, 0, height, 0, GRID.length));
  let markerType = cellType.value();

  if (posx >= 0 && posy >= 0 && posx < GRID[0].length && posy < GRID.length) {
    if (mouseIsPressed && markerType == "START") {
      GRID[startX][startY].isStart = false;
      GRID[posy][posx].isStart = true;
      startX = posy;
      startY = posx;
    }
    if (mouseIsPressed && markerType == "END") {
      GRID[endX][endY].isEnd = false;
      GRID[posy][posx].isEnd = true;
      endX = posy;
      endY = posx;
    }
    if (mouseIsPressed && markerType == "WALLS") {
      GRID[posy][posx].isWall = true;
    }
  }
}

function createHud() {
  startButton = createButton("START");
  startButton.mousePressed(applyAlgo);
  resetButton = createButton("RESET");
  resetButton.mousePressed(initialiseGrid);

  cellType = createSelect();
  cellType.option("WALLS");
  cellType.option("START");
  cellType.option("END");

  algoType = createSelect();
  algoType.option("BREADTH FIRST SEARCH!");
  algoType.option("DEPTH FIRST SEARCH");
  algoType.option("DIJKASHTRA");
  algoType.option("A*");
}

function initialiseGrid() {
  resetVisualisation();
  GRID = create2dArray(floor(height / cellSize), floor(width / cellSize));

  for (let col = 0; col < GRID[0].length; col++) {
    for (let row = 0; row < GRID.length; row++) {
      let newCell = new Cell(col * cellSize, row * cellSize);
      GRID[row][col] = newCell;
    }
  }

  startX = 0;
  startY = 0;
  GRID[startX][startY].isStart = true;
  endX = GRID.length - 1;
  endY = GRID[0].length - 1;
  GRID[endX][endY].isEnd = true;

  addNeighbours();
}

// XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX HELPER FUNCTIONS XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
function create2dArray(m, n) {
  // array of m rows and n columns
  resultArray = [];
  for (let row = 0; row < m; row++) {
    let tempRow = [];
    for (let col = 0; col < n; col++) {
      tempRow.push(0);
    }
    resultArray.push(tempRow);
  }
  return resultArray;
}

function applyAlgo() {
  algo = algoType.value();
  if (algo === "BREADTH FIRST SEARCH!") {
    bfs();
    startAlgoVisualisation();
  }else{
    console.warn(algo,"not yet implemented");
  }
}

function addNeighbours() {
  // add only non diagonal elements
  // add neighbours of non boundary cells
  for (let row = 1; row < GRID.length - 1; row++) {
    for (let col = 1; col < GRID[0].length - 1; col++) {
      let current = GRID[row][col];
      current.neighbours = [
        GRID[row - 1][col],
        GRID[row][col - 1],
        GRID[row + 1][col],
        GRID[row][col + 1]
      ];
    }
  }
  // add neighbours of upper and lower boundary cells
  for (let col = 1; col < GRID[0].length - 1; col++) {
    let upper_boundary = GRID[0][col];
    upper_boundary.neighbours = [
      GRID[0][col - 1],
      GRID[0][col + 1],
      GRID[1][col]
    ];
    let lower_boundary = GRID[GRID.length - 1][col];
    lower_boundary.neighbours = [
      GRID[GRID.length - 1][col - 1],
      GRID[GRID.length - 1][col + 1],
      GRID[GRID.length - 1 - 1][col]
    ];
  }
  // add neighbours of left and right boundary cells
  for (let row = 1; row < GRID.length - 1; row++) {
    let left_boundary = GRID[row][0];
    left_boundary.neighbours = [
      GRID[row - 1][0],
      GRID[row + 1][0],
      GRID[row][1]
    ];
    let right_boundary = GRID[row][GRID[0].length - 1];
    right_boundary.neighbours = [
      GRID[row - 1][GRID[0].length - 1],
      GRID[row + 1][GRID[0].length - 1],
      GRID[row][GRID[0].length - 1 - 1]
    ];
  }
  // add neighbours of four corner cells
  let upper_left_corner = GRID[0][0];
  upper_left_corner.neighbours = [GRID[0 + 1][0], GRID[0][0 + 1]];

  let upper_right_corner = GRID[0][GRID[0].length - 1];
  upper_right_corner.neighbours = [
    GRID[0 + 1][GRID[0].length - 1],
    GRID[0][GRID[0].length - 1 - 1]
  ];

  let lower_right_corner = GRID[GRID.length - 1][GRID[0].length - 1];
  lower_right_corner.neighbours = [
    GRID[GRID.length - 1 - 1][GRID[0].length - 1],
    GRID[GRID.length - 1][GRID[0].length - 1 - 1]
  ];

  let lower_left_corner = GRID[GRID.length - 1][0];
  lower_left_corner.neighbours = [
    GRID[GRID.length - 1 - 1][0],
    GRID[GRID.length - 1][0 + 1]
  ];
}
// XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX HELPER FUNCTIONS XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
function addVisualisationStep(){
  //draw();
  algoVisSteps.push(shallowCopyGrid(GRID));
  console.log("recorded",algoVisSteps.length,"frames");
}

function startAlgoVisualisation(){
  displayAlgoViz = true;
}

function stopAlgoVisualisation(){
  displayAlgoViz = false;
}

function resetVisualisation(){
  stopAlgoVisualisation();
  algoVisStep = 0;
  while(algoVisSteps.length > 0){
    delete algoVisSteps[0];
    algoVisSteps.shift();
  }
}

function shallowCopyGrid(grid){
  let copy = [];
  
  for(let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
    let list = [];
    
    for(let j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++){
      list.push(grid[i][j].shallowCopy());
    }
    
    copy.push(list);
  }
  
  return copy;
}

function bfs() {
  console.log("applying BREADTH FIRST SEARCH");
  let startNode = GRID[startX][startY];
  let endNode = GRID[endX][endY];
  let Q = [];

  startNode.isDiscovered = true;
  Q.push(startNode);

  while (Q.length > 0) {
    let current = Q.shift();
    if (current == endNode) {
      console.log("found end node");
      break;
    } else {
      for (let nebr of current.neighbours) {
        if (nebr.isWall) {
          continue;
        }
        if (!nebr.isDiscovered) {
          nebr.isDiscovered = true;
          nebr.parent = current;
          Q.push(nebr);
          addVisualisationStep();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //   mark the cells which are in the path(that is solution path bw start and end)
  let end = endNode;
  while (end.parent != null) {
    if (!end.isStart) {
      end.isPath = true;
    }
    addVisualisationStep();
    end = end.parent;
  }
}

class Cell {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.isStart = false;
    this.isEnd = false;
    this.isWall = false;
    this.isDiscovered = false;
    this.isPath = false;
    this.parent = null;
    this.neighbours = [];
    this.clr = [255, 255, 255, 255];
  }

  show() {
    if (this.isStart) {
      this.clr = [0, 255, 0, 255];
    } else {
      this.clr = [255, 255, 255, 255];
    }
    if (this.isEnd) {
      this.clr = [255, 0, 0, 255];
    }
    if (this.isWall) {
      this.clr = [51, 51, 51, 255];
    }
    if (this.isDiscovered && !this.isStart) {
      this.clr = [0, 255, 255, 180];
    }
    if (this.isPath) {
      this.clr = [255, 255, 0, 255];
    }
    stroke(115);
    fill(this.clr[0], this.clr[1], this.clr[2], this.clr[3]);
    rect(this.x, this.y, cellSize, cellSize);
  }
  
  // copy without neighbours
  shallowCopy() {
    let copy = new Cell(this.x,this.y);
    
    copy.isStart = this.isStart;
    copy.isEnd = this.isEnd;
    copy.isWall = this.isWall;
    copy.isDiscovered = this.isDiscovered;
    copy.isPath = this.isPath;
    copy.clr = [].concat(this.clr);
    
    return copy;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much you really helped a lot.. appreciate it.!! :)

Comment: Glad it helped: that was fun! Please share a link to the final version after you implement the other 3 algorithms :)